# Aurelia validation not firing with debounce

Tags: aurelia

validations not firing with debounce, i want the server request to wait for some time to complete typing of email on view.

```
 this.validation = validation.on(this)
  .ensure('email').isNotEmpty().isEmail().withMessage("email is required")
  .passes(newValue => {
      return this.webApi.EmailExists(newValue)
                 .then(res => {
                          return !res;
                 });
  }).withMessage("This Email is already registered.")
```

And my View is :

```
 <div class="form-group fg-float fg-line">
    <input type="text" value.bind="searchFields.emailId & debounce">
    <label class="fg-label"></label> 
 </div>
```

Comment: You could try something simple like setTimeout, if the variable you bound to the validtation changes within the time setTimeout needs, you dont do anything. If it doesn't, you fire your event.

Answer (score 2):

It completely depends on the version of aurelia-validation you are using. It seems like you are using a version from before the rework. I propose you try the following for e.g. version 0.6.8:

```
this.validation = validation.on(this)
    .ensure('email', config => {
        config.useDebounceTimeout(150);
    })
    .isNotEmpty().isEmail().withMessage("email is required")
    .passes(newValue => {
        return this.webApi.EmailExists(newValue)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.exists) {
                    reject('This Email is already registered.');
                } else {
                    accept();
                }
            });
    });
```

Then, you can remove the debounce binding behavior from your view.

---

However, if you decide to update to the latest release (1.0.0-beta.1.0.1), you can try the following.

Your **View-Model** should look like this:

```
import {inject, NewInstance} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {ValidationController, ValidationRules, validateTrigger} from 'aurelia-validation';

@inject(ValidationController)
export class SignUp {
    constructor(validationController) {
        this.validationController = validationController;
        this.validationController.validateTrigger = validateTrigger.change;
        ValidationRules
            .ensure('email').required().email()
            .then()
            .satisfies((newValue) => {
                return new Promise((accept, reject) => {
                    this.webApi.EmailExists(newValue).then(data => {
                        if (data.exists) {
                            accept(false);
                        } else {
                            accept(true);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }).withMessage(`\${$displayName} is already taken.`)
            .on(this);
    }
}
```

Your **View** would be:

```
<div class="form-group fg-float fg-line">
  <input type="text" value.bind="searchFields.emailId & validate & debounce">
  <label class="fg-label"></label> 
</div>
```

This will trigger validation each time you change the value in your input (because of the *validateTrigger.change*. If you remove that line, validation will be triggered on blur (if you leave that field).